# Query of past events for a "like" page is not returning full list (as shown on actual page)

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

The code used to query (below) has not changed since before it was working correctly, but [the page](http://utsarotaract.org/events.php?tab=past) suddenly started only displaying one of the *many* past events. Has the functionality of the QL changed in some way or is this just a bug that I should wait and see if it passes?

```
SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, eid 
FROM event 
WHERE end_time < now() 
AND eid IN ( 
    SELECT eid 
    FROM event_member 
    WHERE uid = XXXXXXXXX ) 
ORDER BY start_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but FQL's documentation on event_member might be the key. Have you attempted running only the internal query (`SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = XXXXXXXXX`) alone without the wrapper to see what it's returning?

[FQL documentation for event_member](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) states that

> If you do not specify a start_time, only events in the future will be returned.

**EDIT**: I take this to mean that you may, currently, need to specify `start_time < now()` in there, or something of the like.

(Though, if that's case, I'm not sure why you're even getting the one item returned because that would conflict with your `end_time < now()` statement).

My first suggestion might be to spit it into multiple queries using FQL multiquery and make sure that the event_member query is returning what you'd expect.
Something like:

```
"event_members":"SELECT eid 
FROM event_member 
WHERE uid = XXXXXXXXX"

"events":"SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, eid 
FROM event 
WHERE end_time < now() 
AND eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #event_members) 
ORDER BY start_time DESC"
```

See that event_members holds all the entries you're hoping for - if so, find the issue in the 'events' query, if not, find the issue in the 'event_members' query.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Like I said, the query was working prior to now (with no modifications since), but I'll try splitting it up and see if I can figure out where the issue is occurring and post back.

Comment: Did event_members return what you expected? (A rather more extended list of eids). Otherwise, have you tried adding some specification about start_time to the event_members query? :)